# How to put condition on questions to grey out (having questions in HTML with radio button answer ) using NA button for each question?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created one HTML/JS application in which i have created 5 questions with radio button answer.i have given user to do click NA for not applicable questions.but i want to put condition that user only able to grey out 3 questions.Not more than that here i am confused how to do it.below is the code.Also i have put Next button with condition so each question which is not grey out should be answer :-

HTML :-

```
<div class="section-1-questions">
                    <div style="background-color:greenyellow;"> <b>Section 1:</b> </div><br>
                      <fieldset class="form-group">
                              <div class="row1">
                                 <div class = "question1">
                                <legend id="q1" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-0"><b>1) Question 1</b></legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1" >
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                                          Never
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                                          Rarely
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                          Occasionally
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios4" value="4">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                                              Often
                                                          </label>
                                      </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios5" value="5">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                                          Always
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                 
                                  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="q1Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(1)" />
    <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" oninput="updateTextBox()" />
    <p>Remaining Characters: <span id="chars-left">100</span></p>
</div>
 

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="disable1" id = "na1" value="N/A"/>
</div>
                              
                              </div></div>
 </div>
                              {{!-- <input type="button" id="remarks" value="Remarks" /> --}}
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                              <div class="row1">
                                <legend id="q2" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>2) Question 2</b></legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                                          Never
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios7" value="2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                                          Rarely
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios8" value="3">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                      Occasionally
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios9" value="4">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                                            Often
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios10" value="5">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                                              Always
                                                          </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="button" name="q2Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(2)" />
                                            <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput2" value="" />
                                          </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                              <div class="row1">
                                <legend id="q3" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>3) Question 3</b></legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios11" value="1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                                          Never
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios12" value="2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                                          Rarely
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios13" value="3">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                      Occasionally
                                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios14" value="4">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                                            Often
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios15" value="5">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                                              Always
                                                          </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="button" name="q3Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(3)" />
                                            <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput3" value="" />
                                          </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <div class="row1">
                                  <legend id="q4" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>4) Question 4</b></legend>
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                                            Never
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                                            Rarely
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                          Occasionally
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios19" value="4">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                                              Often
                                                          </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios20" value="5">
                                          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                                                Always
                                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="button" name="q4Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(4)" />
                                            <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput4" value="" />
                                          </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </fieldset>
                              <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <div class="row1">
                                  <legend id="q5" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>5) QUESTION 5</b></legend>
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios21" value="1">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                                            Never
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios22" value="2">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios22">
                                                            Rarely
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios23" value="3">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios23">
                                          Occasionally
                                                          </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios24" value="4">
                                          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios24">
                                                                Often
                                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios25" value="5">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios25">
                                                            Always
                                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="button" name="q5Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(5)" />
                                            <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput5" value="" />
                                          </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </fieldset>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="remarks"><b>Remarks / Observations </b></label>
                                    <input type="name" class="form-control" name="Remarks1" id="remarks1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Please enter your Remarks / Observations">
                                    <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your Remarks / Observations about these questions.</small>
                                  </div>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a>
                          <a class="btn btn-primary btnNextS1" >Next</a>
                        </div>
```

JS  :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#na1").click(function() {
  console.log("na is working");
  $(".question1 input").attr('disabled', true);
})
});
$('.btnNextS1').click(function(){
  if($('div.row1:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length){
    $('div.row1:not(:has(:radio:checked))').parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please Answer this question</div>");
  }else {
  // e.stopPropagation();
$('ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item     a.active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each question has identical information, why not do it once and repeat.

For the NA button, we just add a class onto the enclosing div which helps us with styling and also gives us a selector to test for legnth. When it's over 3 we prevent it from continuing.

Sorry I changed the code, but hopefully this will give you some insight on how to make your code more lean, managable and responsive. Now if you want to update the answers, you can do it once and it works for them all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let ctr = 1;
  $('.answers').each(function(index) {
    let i = index + 1
    let html = ` <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question${i}" id="gridRadios${ctr}" value="1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios${ctr}"> Never</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question${i}" id="gridRadios${ctr}" value="2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios${ctr}">Rarely</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question${i}" id="gridRadios${ctr}" value="3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios${ctr}">Occasionally</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question${i}" id="gridRadios${ctr}" value="4">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios${ctr}">Often</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question${i}" id="gridRadios${ctr}" value="5">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios${ctr}">Always</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="q${i}Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(${i})" />
    <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput${i}" value="" oninput="updateTextBox()" />
    <p>Remaining Characters: <span id="chars-left">100</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button name="disable${i}" id="na${i}" class='btn-na'>N/A</button>
    </div>
    `
    $(this).html(html);
    ctr++;
  })




  $(".btn-na").click(function() {
    let n = $('.answers.disabled').length
    if (n >= 3) {
      alert('You can only disable 3');
      return
    }
    $(this).closest('.answers').find("input").attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).closest('.answers').addClass('disabled')
  })
});

$('.btnNextS1').click(function() {
  if ($('div.row1:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length) {
    $('div.row1:not(:has(:radio:checked))').parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please Answer this question</div>");
  } else {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item     a.active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```css
.answers.disabled {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-1-questions">
  <div style="background-color:greenyellow;"> <b>Section 1:</b> </div><br>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="question1">
        <legend id="q1" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-0"><b>1) Question 1</b></legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10 answers">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row1">
      <legend id="q2" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>2) Question 2</b></legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10 answers">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row1">
      <legend id="q3" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>3) Question 3</b></legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10 answers">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row1">
      <legend id="q4" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>4) Question 4</b></legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10 answers">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row1">
      <legend id="q5" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-3"><b>5) QUESTION 5</b></legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10 answers">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="remarks"><b>Remarks / Observations </b></label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" name="Remarks1" id="remarks1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Please enter your Remarks / Observations">
    <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your Remarks / Observations about these questions.</small>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btnNextS1">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not place your `html` javascript variable into a for loop and set your `value` attribute to equal your iterator + 1 (you're already using `i` so maybe have use another iterator variable)? After that you can append the `.form-group` divs to the end of the string? This would easily clean up some of that redundant javascript code

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `disabled` html attribute along with the jquery `prop` function.

```
$(".class").prop( "disabled", true );
```

It's important to note that using `disabled` and `required` on the same element can cause problems for users. This is because they won't be able to submit the form because a `input` is disabled, preventing input, but it's also required.

**EDIT**

You'll want to define a "counter" variable `var disableCount = 0;` which will increment every time a question is disabled. Once the counter variable is incremented three times. The click function should `1` Stop incrementing the counter and `2` stop disabling questions.
Something like this should work:

```
var disableCount = 0;

$("#na1").click(function() {

    if(disableCount >= 3) return;

    console.log("na is working");
    $(".question1 input").attr('disabled', true);

    disableCount++;
});
```

Comment: i am already able to disable question but i want to put condition so that user only able to disable 3 question and other 2 he need to answer.

Comment: @jugal ohh I see, let me update my post with what you're looking for

Comment: @Kinglish How can i make next button work ? It is still not moving to next session as after disable question still it is asking to answer them before moving next